# ListView ItemCommand not being reached on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I  have an aspx page using listview.  The delete button I have needs to execute a sql delete using an ID found in the list view.

ASPX:

```
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView2" OnItemDataBound="ListView2_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ListView2_ItemCommand">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    ...
                    <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="10" OnPreRender="DataPager_PreRender">
                        <Fields>
                           ...
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    ...
                      <td runat="server" align="right" colspan="4"><asp:Button ID="deleteRButton" CssClass="Button" runat="server" Text="Delete"  CommandName="deleteRButton" OnClientClick="return confirm('You are about to delete this forum response.  Are you sure you want to proceed?');" /></td>
                    ...
                </ItemTemplate>
         <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
         </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ListView2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.CommandName == "deleteRButton") //Never makes it here with breakpoints
        {
            ...
            //Find label value and execute SQL
        }

    }
```

How do I get the button click to execute the Item Command code?  I have tried using an OnClick method as well (which fires) but I don't have access to the label ID value that way.

**EDIT:**

Sharing page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetQuestions(); //builds data table and binds to listview 1
        GetAnswers(); //builds data table and binds to listview 2
        questionIDBreadCrumb.Text = grabID(); //grabs id from url
        //loads the current userID
        getUserData();
     }
```

Comment: If Possible, do share your `Page_Load` Event.

Comment: @Prabhat see the edit

Comment: Wrap `getUserData();` inside `If (!IsPostback) { ... }` and run again. Better if wrap all content inside `!IsPostback`.

Comment: Throwing everything inside of If (!IsPostback) {...} solved the issue and now the ItemCommand Event is being reached.  Thank you!

EDIT: How can I mark as solved?  Or do I not have enough rep yet?

Comment: Pleasure helping you :) You can post what changes you did in your code as answer and mark it as accepted. This will close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Putting the page load events inside if (!ispostback) solved the issue.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetQuestions();
            GetAnswers();
            questionIDBreadCrumb.Text = grabID();

            //loads the current userID
            getUserData();
            //validates questionOwner
        }
```